# node pm2 not working (debian)

Tags: node.js, debian, pm2

I'm using last nodejs (0.10.26) on Debian.
I installed the last version of pm2 (1.1.63) and it didnt show any errors while installing

i can run pm2 without parameters. Everything is ok. 
But when I'm trying to run **pm2 start app.js** it shows an error

```
/var/node/server/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/usage/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
              ^
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 11, got 1.
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at bindings (/var/node/server/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/usage/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/node/server/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/usage/lib/usage.js:1:100)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

so, i read a lot and reinstall everything and installed package for building (node-gyp). but still having the same bug.. maybe its a general problem ... 
Does anyone knows what to do?